# how to set a link text while adding link in sitemap?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I was trying to add a link in the sitemap. you can see in following picture what I got after I import the `customizations` xml.

[image]

how to change the name "Unknown3205" ???

I have added this following XML setting:

```
 <Group Id="Extensions" ResourceId="Group_Extensions">
          <SubArea Id="new_Edit_Trip" Url="$Webresource:new_/Edit_Task.htm"/>
          .....................
          ...................
        </Group>
```

What is wrong with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify attribute `Title` into `SubArea`. Something like this:

```
<SubArea Id="new_Edit_Trip" Title="Edit Task" Url="$Webresource:new_/Edit_Task.htm"/>
```